# smartcard select mf return 69 86 command not allowed (no current ef)

Tags: smartcard, apdu

When I try to select MF using apdu's below:

`00 A4 00 00` or `00 A4 00 00 02 3F 00`

I get 69 89, command not allowed (no current ef) error.

I am new to smartcards, is there anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `00A40004023F00`. Are you sure there is a file system on your smart card?

Comment: result is same for '00A40004023F00'. I am not sure about this. What can I do if there is not, can I create a file system or do I need to use a different type smart card?

Comment: @Jabajubhyl That's somewhat hard to tell, we don't know the type of card you are currently using.

Comment: Your card may either *not yet* have a file system (refer to the manual how to create one) or simply have no MF (javacard?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your smartcard is [probably](https://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3BBE1800004105100000000000000000009000) an [ACOS5 card](http://eurzad.alfatv.pl/etoken/Acos/ACOS5%20SDK%20v3.0.1.3/Data/Documents/REF_ACOS5_v2.00.pdf).

The `6986` response to the SELECT command means "No MF found in card" (see section 5.2).

You need to create MF first using the "Create File" command (see section 5.1).

Good luck!

Comment: I get the 67 00, wrong length error while creating mf, what should be the correct command? (second picture shows my command)

Comment: Probably `00 E0 00 00 0C 62 0A 82 01 3F 83 02 3F 00 8A 01 01`. But you *REALLY* should read the documentation (as this command creates the file in "Creation/Initialization state"). Have a look to the [sample code](http://eurzad.alfatv.pl/etoken/Acos/ACOS5%20SDK%20v3.0.1.3/Data/Sample%20Codes/) as well.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, as I understand working on smart cards requires a deep knowladge. Is it easier to read/write on [memory cards](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/1141/PMA_ACx30.pdf)?

Comment: It probably depends on your use case. You are right that memory cards are much easier for basic read/write use (but keep in mind that you need your particular card reader to support the particular memory card to be able to access it). On the other hand with a smart card you have much more control regarding data structure, access control, etc. Maybe post a separate question asking which card technology suits your use case the best (I am not sure it would be "on topic" for SO, but definitely there are users who know a lot about smart cards). Good luck!